# Book about a clone of a dead son

Tags: story-identification, clones

I'm looking for a book that was almost certainly written in the '90s and is about two people who lose their son in an accident on a boat (pretty sure about the boat part) and decide to clone him. The clone ends up reading the boy's diary and kills himself.

Comment: It's a film, but *Cloned* in 1997 fits your criteria in some ways:
"In the year 2008, a married couple is distraught over losing their 8 year old son in a boating accident. However, when the mother suddenly sees another child who looks identical to her dead child, the Mother investigates the fertility clinic who aided her with her pregnancy and discovers that they cloned her child in an experiment dubbed "Baby 2000". She also discovers that they still have the genes to develop another child for them and faces the question of whether the couple wants another identical child."